# Deceptive Dissection

Tags: geometry, dissection

Divide the below figure into $5$ equal pieces (same shape, same size, possibly reflected).

$\qquad\quad\qquad$[image]

I believe this is one of Martin Gardner's, but I could not find the source.

Comment: I think the dashed lines are misleading: if you consider them, we have a total area of 16 squares to divide into 5 parts

Comment: I actually find the dashed lines helpful, as they give me the relative sizes of each portion of the shape

Comment: I think this might have been in one of the Aha! books?

Comment: @zeb, thank you, you are right! This appears in aha! Insight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first observation we make is that

> the left and right edges are identical
>  the top and bottom edges are identical

If we then

> mark four equidistant points along each horizontal line,

we have constructed the basis for making 5 shapes that are basically

> thinner versions of the original shape.

Connecting the dots vertically now subdivides the original shape into 5 equal pieces of the same shape and size.

> ```
> x-x-x-x-x-x
>  \ \ \ \ \ \
>  / / / / / /
> | | | | | |
> x-x-x-x-x-x
> ```

Perhaps the most important observation to make is that

> the lattice on which this shape is placed is a visual distraction. Once ignored and only the shape itself is considered, the solution is quite obvious.

Comment: This means we could divide this into an infinite number of identical shapes, right?

Comment: @VictorHenry You sure could. It's not what the puzzle was asking for, though.